# Bash Substitute a Variable in a variable

Tags: bash

I'm Banging my head end can not find the Answer.

I want to use a directory `INPUT_DIR` within a other Variable `MINFILESIZE` (Checking in a directory if there is a file large then 50 MB and echo that file)

I have so far

```
INPUT_DIR="${1%/*}"

MINFILESIZE="find ${INPUT_DIR} -type f -size +50M"

Echo"Minfile: $MINFILESIZE"
```

And i can not get it to work.

Comment: So what's your problem ? ("I can't make it work" is not a valid problem)

Comment: Please edit the question and use the `{}` button from the editor's toolbar to nicely format the code.

Comment: Its my first time please be nice.

Comment: If i execute this on a directory it will not output the file a expect it to output.

Comment: "Its my first time please be nice." -> That's what she said. Couldn't resist, but lets focus on your question, i would highly suggest you to take the [tour], visit the [ask] page and the following link on how to build a [mcve], it will help you understand how the site works and how to ask a proper question :) (in order to avoid bashing ^^). Also if it's not working what is it doing then :) ?

Comment: You need back-quotes instead of regular double-quotes.  I prefer the `$( .. )` syntax: `MINFILESIZE=$( find ${INPUT_DIR} -type f -size +50M )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting `MINFILESIZE` to a string. The output is going to output that variable as a string, not give you the output of the command. You can have bash run this as a command one of two ways. Use backticks `` ` .. ` `` or use `$( .. )` for [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html). Bash will interpret the command inside and give the output you expect as the value for your variable:

```
MINFILESIZE=$( find ${INPUT_DIR} -type f -size +50M )
```

The `$( .. )` style is recommended, since this is the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03) standard.